# iOS 7 screen is still shaking after reboot

Tags: iphone, ios

I have tried changing the Parallax setting (general>accessibility>reduce motion).  Still shaking!!

Weird thing...the shaking only appeared after re-booting my phone the first time after updating to ios 7.  After updating to iOS 7 initially, the screen did not shake.  Strange?

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

I had it very bad since the upgrade - 24/7 - I changed my settings (General > Accessibility > Invert Colours) to invert the colours and it worked.  It's a bandaide but at least I can read my messages and mail.  My pictures however look like negatives..